# How to call error handler in a function? Not an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I have a normal function which called inside an API function.In API function i will call next(err) since I have an common error handler but how do I throw error in normal function without passing next in params?

```
const xxx = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    normalFunction(data);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

function normalFunction(data) {
  try {
  } catch (e) {
    // how to throw error here??
  }
}
```

Comment: you can write a `throw` statement to throw any value you want, though generally an instance of `Error` is a good idea.

Comment: there a simple documentation for that... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception.
> Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack.
> If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate

```
function normalFunction(data) {
  try {
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e); // Could also be a specific string, number, ...
  }
}
```